# Load CSV with headers into rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import

I've reviewed many, many responses and still unable to preload rails 5 table with csv file. This is my first attempt to load data from rails console. Please help!

csv file formats liket this with CSV.foreach()

```
["model_id", "model_make_id", "model_name", "model_trim", "model_year", "model_make_display_name"]
["44328", "acura", "MDX", nil, "2011", "Acura"]
["44331", "acura", "RDX", nil, "2011", "Acura"]
["44332", "acura", "RDX", "SH-AWD", "2011", "Acura"]
["44334", "acura", "RL", nil, "2011", "Acura"]
["44337", "acura", "TL", nil, "2011", "Acura"]
```

.rb file code

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('./tmp/cq_sample.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
  record = Cqref.new(
    :model_id                 => row[0], # first column of csv file
    :model_make_id            => row[1], # second column
    :model_name               => row[2], # third
    :model_trim               => row[3], # fourth
    :model_year               => row[4], # fifth
    :model_make_display_name  => row[5]  # sixth
  )
  record.save
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "cqrefs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "model_id"
    t.string   "model_make_id"
    t.string   "model_name"
    t.string   "model_trim"
    t.string   "model_year"
    t.string   "model_make_display_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end
```

Error Mesage Extract:

```
require './tmp/importcsv'
ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: model_name is defined by Active Record. Check to make sure that you don't have an attribute or method with the same name.
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:91:in `instance_method_already_implemented?'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:288:in `block in define_attribute_method'
```

Comment: you will have to change the attribute `model_name` to something else as it is [reserved by Active Record](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DangerousAttributeError.html)

Comment: What is your DB?

Comment: as @ImranAli mentioned, the word _model_name_ is claimed by rails. See this link for more info https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18338

Comment: This worked! I changed the attribute name by prepending two characters hit enter in console and it worked. I'm a noob spent hours search and never made that connection. My heart leapt when I say updates flashing across my console! Thanks so much!!!